# Flask application not returning the predicted value

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, flask

I have created a Flask application to deploy a simple Machine Learning algorithm. I have created the app.py file, the model.py file. My model.py file is getting compiled and returning the correct result when run from the command prompt. But when I execute the app.py file it does provide the html page as the output. But when I enter the input values and click the "Predict" button I'm unable to see the final output or prediction on the html page. What am I doing wrong here?

```
model.py file:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle

dataset = pd.read_csv('hiring.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, :3]
print(X.columns)

y = dataset.iloc[:, -1]

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()

regressor.fit(X, y)

pickle.dump(regressor, open('model1.pkl','wb'))

model = pickle.load(open('model1.pkl','rb'))
print(model.predict([[2, 8, 9]]))

app.py file:

import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)

model = pickle.load(open('model1.pkl','rb'))

@app.route('/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():

    int_features = [int(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)

    output = round(prediction[0], 2)

    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='Employee Salary should be $ 
    {}'.format(output))

    if __name__ == "__main__":
            app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: if __name__ == "__main__" -  This statement should not be indented. It would cause the flask service to not run.

Answer (score 0):

You have indented

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

into your `predict` function

You will be able to solve your problem by fixing this indentation issue.

Your code should be like this :

```
model.py file:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle

dataset = pd.read_csv('hiring.csv')

X = dataset.iloc[:, :3]
print(X.columns)

y = dataset.iloc[:, -1]

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()

regressor.fit(X, y)

pickle.dump(regressor, open('model1.pkl','wb'))

model = pickle.load(open('model1.pkl','rb'))
print(model.predict([[2, 8, 9]]))

app.py file:

import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)

model = pickle.load(open('model1.pkl','rb'))

@app.route('/',methods=["GET","POST"])
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():

    int_features = [int(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)

    output = round(prediction[0], 2)

    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text='Employee Salary should be $ 
    {}'.format(output))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```